# Component are not update after redirect back from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I've created small ReactJS app and get retrieve user feeds data from facebook api.

If data not shown, call NodeJS api and fetch feeds from facebook and redirect back to index screen. Problem is once redirect back, I found that feeds is already in database and after redirect back to index page, feeds are not shown, I need to reload browser screen.

My problem is which component should I use after redirect back to original screen in react?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReloadButton from './ReloadButton';
import Feeds from './Feeds';
import Alert from './Alert';

class MyTest extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            feeds: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/fetch')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ feeds: data }));
    }

    render() {
        const { feeds } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <a className="btn btn-primary" href="/auth/facebook">Reload</a>
                { feeds.length > 0 ? <Feeds feeds={ feeds } /> : <Alert /> }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MyTest;
```

Comment: this component did not work? your code seems normal if you want to load data in initial status only, have you check the response data in your code? As you know 'componentDidMount' called when component loaded and never call again until a component Rerender again. if you want to rerender your component by clicking the 'a' tag you have to set method and set your state in that Ajax call.

Comment: @AlirezaYadegari first time, there is no data in database. at that time, I've to click `reload` button and page will be redirect to `\auth\facebook` and fetch data and save it to database, and redirect back to that page. at that time, date will not be displayed even data are in database, so I need to reload browser. that's problem.

Answer (score 0):

if I were you I did something like this. please say if it is helpful

```
interface ExampleProps {
    someDataFacebookSendMe: any; //this prop used to get redirect from facebook and for first time is null
}

interface ExampleState {
    feeds: []
    spinning: boolean;
    isDataCollected: boolean; // this proprty check for gotten data
}
export class Example extends React.Component<ExampleProps, ExampleState> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            feeds: [],
            spinning: true,
            isDataCollected: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (!!this.props.someDataFacebookSendMe) {

            while (!this.state.isDataCollected) {
                this.getData()
            }

            fetch('/fetch')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {

                        this.setState({ feeds: data, spinning: false, isDataCollected: true })
                    }
                });
        }
        else {
            this.setState({spinning: false})
        }
    }

    getData() {
        fetch('/fetchIsDataExists') // this method check if data has gotten or not
            .then(data => this.setState({isDataCollected: true }));
    }

    render() {
        const { feeds } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <Spin spinning={spinning} >
                    <a className="btn btn-primary" href="/auth/facebook">Reload</a>
                    {feeds.length > 0 ? <Feeds feeds={feeds} /> : <Alert />}
                </Spin>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```